# How to remove paragraph tag inside <td> from every row while exporting as PDF or Excel in jQuery DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

[I want to remove paragraph with class td-para](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SLyv.png)[image: I need to remove view, contacts and delete while exporting (there are html elments in every row)]

I was trying to export in PDF, Excel, and CSV while using jQuery DataTables.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74259396/edit) to show an example of your HTML markup, and describe exactly which tag(s) you want to remove.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.